# Select from two columns maximum values

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, max, worksheet-function

I have two columns of data in Excel:

```
30796.03 50779.57
17220    19315.76
57891.   77629.74
2046.2   3306.86
21883        NULL
740607       NULL
540000   740988
180      297.03
25200    34110.72
74793.79    NULL
4800     7981.44
21600    35935.92
3840     6468.67
27000    4 093.05
636      1061.74
```

For column 2, if it DIFFERS from column 1, I want to replace column 1 with that different column 2 value.

If column 2 show's NULL, then keep column 1 as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a separate column please try:

```
=IF(B1="NULL",A1,B1)
```

copied down to suit.

If the next to last entry under B is a typo you *might* be able to use:

```
=MAX(A1,B1)
```

but this assumes ColumnB is either `NULL` or *always* more than the corresponding ColumnA value.

Comment: Hi pnuts. Yes - columnB will always be NULL or ALWAYS be more than Column A. (and yes it was a typo!)